# Regex for matching and separating strings

Tags: regex, string, dart

I want to separate that strings (only the strings in English) from this messed string:

```
"[[[\"Dude, that was insane! \",\"Cara, aquilo foi insano!\",null,null,3],[\"How did you do that? \",\"
```

I was trying to make a regex using Dart, but it doesn't match:

```
  var regex = RegExp(r'[\"([\w+\s]*)\s\",\"');
  Iterable<Match> matches = regex.allMatches(returnString)
  matches.forEach((match) {
    print(match.group(0));
  });
```

> FormatException: Unmatched ')'[\"([\w+.\s]*)\s\",\"

Can someone help me? How can I make a good regex? I'm new at it so sorry about my lack of knowledge.

Comment: go to https://regexr.com/ and test your input and then use it in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var regex = RegExp(r'"[^"]*"');
```

which will display:

```
"Dude, that was insane! "
"Cara, aquilo foi insano!"
"How did you do that? "
```

Note that your string looks really like a json string and if it is you should use [json codec](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-convert/json-constant.html) to decode it and recursively go through the tree to collect strings.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this pattern surrounded by '\B...\B' and it matchs!